# Laravel get all conversations by the column user_id and every conversation should get all the messages

Tags: laravel

i have a table Conversations
Conversations has many conversations

and i have Messages Table
Messages table has many messages
Messages table contains a row where every message in the table has a row conversation_id
this indicate that every message belong to a conversation

im able to use

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 /**
 * Get the Messages for the Conversation chat.
 */
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
}
```

in the controller im able to get all messages that belongs to that conversation (1)

```
$messages = App\Conversation::find(1)->messages ;
```

what i want is i want to get all conversations by the column user_id and every conversation should get all the messages?
array of conversation
something like this if possible

```
[
  //conversation 0 
  [ 
    [
      id: 1
      message : "Bla bla bla",     
    ],
    [
      id: 2
      message : "Response to Bla bla bla",     
    ],
    [
      id: 3
      message : "Bye",     
    ]  
  ],
  //conversation 1 
  [ 
    [
      id: 1
      message : "Bla bla bla",     
    ] 
  ],
    //conversation 2 
  [ 
    [
      id: 1
      message : "Bla bla bla",     
    ] 
  ],
]
```

how do i do this please i dont know what should i use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like to get conversations of user:

```
$conversations = App\Conversation::with('messages')->where('user_id', $id)->get();
```

Where `$id` is user id and `with('messages')` return collection of messages for conversation. To access this you can do simply like:

```
foreach($conversations as $conversation){
  $conversation->messages;
}
```

Comment: thank you Sir that worked great ill love to read about this from the documentation if you can provide a link for it, thank you again

Comment: Here it is [Click](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: And here also [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)